# Using monotonically_increasing_id() for assigning row number to pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, indexing, merge, pyspark

I am using monotonically_increasing_id() to assign row number to pyspark dataframe using syntax below:

```
df1 = df1.withColumn("idx", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Now df1 has 26,572,528 records. So I was expecting idx value from 0-26,572,527.

But when I select max(idx), its value is strangely huge: 335,008,054,165.

What's going on with this function?
is it reliable to use this function for merging with another dataset having similar number of records?

I have some 300 dataframes which I want to combine into a single dataframe. So one dataframe contains IDs and others contain different records corresponding to them row-wise

Comment: RDD zipWithIndex() seemed to be a reliable option

Comment: For sequential IDs using `row_number()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67474910/985766

Comment: If you're trying to build a key to join multiple dataframes across, i'd avoid this for performance reasons. a row_number() function will force all of your data into a single partition, killing performance.

A better option would be to create a GUID column out of the key fields in the dataframe, and use that to join with (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sha2.html)

Comment: When joining large numbers of tables like this, your best option is to use a melt-union-cast (aka pivot longer - union - pivot wider) approach.
If all your dataframes are of the form: idx | var1 | var2 | var3 | ....
then you can melt them into this format:
```idx | variable | value \n
123 | var1 | value \n
123 | var2 | value \n
...
```
All the tables will then have the same columns, so you can simply union them together to make a huge table. Then, cast (pivot) to get the dataframe back into the traditional wide format.

(Well, I can't seem to do newlines properly in this comment)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Edit**: Full examples of the ways to do this and the risks can be found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/adding-sequential-ids-to-a-spark-dataframe-fa0df5566ff6)

From the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id)

> A column that generates monotonically increasing 64-bit integers.
>
> The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, but not consecutive. The current implementation puts the partition ID in the upper 31 bits, and the record number within each partition in the lower 33 bits. The assumption is that the data frame has less than 1 billion partitions, and each partition has less than 8 billion records.

Thus, it is not like an auto-increment id in RDBs and it is **not** reliable for merging.

If you need an auto-increment behavior like in RDBs and your data is sortable, then you can use `row_number`

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')
spark.sql('select row_number() over (order by "some_column") as num, * from df')
+---+-----------+
|num|some_column|
+---+-----------+
|  1|   ....... |
|  2|   ....... |
|  3| ..........|
+---+-----------+
```

If your data is not sortable and you don't mind using rdds to create the indexes and then fall back to dataframes, you can use `rdd.zipWithIndex()`

An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48165635/3433323)

In short:

```
# since you have a dataframe, use the rdd interface to create indexes with zipWithIndex()
df = df.rdd.zipWithIndex()
# return back to dataframe
df = df.toDF()

df.show()

# your data           | indexes
+---------------------+---+
|         _1          | _2| 
+-----------=---------+---+
|[data col1,data col2]|  0|
|[data col1,data col2]|  1|
|[data col1,data col2]|  2|
+---------------------+---+
```

You will probably need some more transformations after that to get your dataframe to what you need it to be. Note: not a very performant solution.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

**Edit:**
Come to think about it, you can combine the `monotonically_increasing_id` to use the `row_number`:

```
# create a monotonically increasing id 
df = df.withColumn("idx", monotonically_increasing_id())

# then since the id is increasing but not consecutive, it means you can sort by it, so you can use the `row_number`
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')
new_df = spark.sql('select row_number() over (order by "idx") as num, * from df')
```

Not sure about performance though.

Comment: can i get row_number without sorting. As I don't want to sort them, rather use as it is. RDDs seem to be lot of back and forth for some 300 dataframes

Comment: @muni Unfortunately `row_number` is a windowing function and it cannot be used without sorting. Take a look at the updated answer, as it might help.

Comment: if we are sorting by "idx", then we don't really need the row_number for joining right? I can directly use "idx"

Comment: @muni yes, but idx is not consecutive, which means you cannot do a count and compare different dataframes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162995/discussion-between-muni-and-mkaran).

Answer (score 30):

using api functions you can do simply as the following

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1 = df1.withColumn("idx", F.monotonically_increasing_id())
windowSpec = W.orderBy("idx")
df1 = df1.withColumn("idx", F.row_number().over(windowSpec)).show()
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Please be extra careful with the answer since it moves all the rows into a single partition (which may cause OOM).

Comment: @JeffEvans Because of the window specification that does not use any `partitionBy` and uses one partition only for `row_number()`.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski we could select only "idx", add the row_number (resulting in df2), and in the end merge df1 via "idx" with df2 to get the row_number into df1. This should decrease risk of OOM, shouldn't it?

Comment: "merge" like a join? That'd be a self-join and could indeed lower the risk of OOM.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution by @mkaran useful, But for me there was no ordering column while using window function. I wanted to maintain the order of rows of dataframe as their indexes (what you would see in a pandas dataframe). Hence the solution in edit section came of use. Since it is a good solution (if performance is not a concern), I would like to share it as a separate answer.

```
df_index = sdf_drop.withColumn("idx", monotonically_increasing_id())

# Create the window specification
w = Window.orderBy("idx")

# Use row number with the window specification
df_index = df_index.withColumn("index", F.row_number().over(w))

# Drop the created increasing data column
df2_index = df_index.drop("idx")
```

`df` is your original dataframe and `df_index` is new dataframe.

Comment: Maybe we should careful with row number `df_index`  if it starts at 1, so you'd have to subtract 1 to have it start from 0 as it mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52318817/10452700)

Answer (score 3):

Building on @mkaran answer,

`df.coalesce(1).withColumn("idx", monotonicallyIncreasingId())`

Using `.coalesce(1)` puts the Dataframe in one partition, and so have monotonically increasing *and* successive index column. Make sure it's reasonably sized to be in one partition so you avoid potential problems afterwards.
Worth noting that I sorted my Dataframe in ascending order beforehand.

Here's a preview comparison of what it looked like for me, with and without coalesce, where I had a summary Dataframe of 50 rows,

`df.coalesce(1).withColumn("No", monotonicallyIncreasingId()).show(60)`

| startTimes | endTimes | No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-11-01 05:39:50 | 2019-11-01 06:12:50 | 0 |
| 2019-11-01 06:23:10 | 2019-11-01 06:23:50 | 1 |
| 2019-11-01 06:26:49 | 2019-11-01 06:46:29 | 2 |
| 2019-11-01 07:00:29 | 2019-11-01 07:04:09 | 3 |
| 2019-11-01 15:24:29 | 2019-11-01 16:04:59 | 4 |
| 2019-11-01 16:23:38 | 2019-11-01 17:27:58 | 5 |
| 2019-11-01 17:32:18 | 2019-11-01 17:47:58 | 6 |
| 2019-11-01 17:54:18 | 2019-11-01 18:00:00 | 7 |
| 2019-11-02 04:42:40 | 2019-11-02 04:49:20 | 8 |
| 2019-11-02 05:11:40 | 2019-11-02 05:22:00 | 9 |

`df.withColumn("runNo", monotonically_increasing_id).show(60)`

| startTimes | endTimes | No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-11-01 05:39:50 | 2019-11-01 06:12:50 | 0 |
| 2019-11-01 06:23:10 | 2019-11-01 06:23:50 | 8589934592 |
| 2019-11-01 06:26:49 | 2019-11-01 06:46:29 | 17179869184 |
| 2019-11-01 07:00:29 | 2019-11-01 07:04:09 | 25769803776 |
| 2019-11-01 15:24:29 | 2019-11-01 16:04:59 | 34359738368 |
| 2019-11-01 16:23:38 | 2019-11-01 17:27:58 | 42949672960 |
| 2019-11-01 17:32:18 | 2019-11-01 17:47:58 | 51539607552 |
| 2019-11-01 17:54:18 | 2019-11-01 18:00:00 | 60129542144 |
| 2019-11-02 04:42:40 | 2019-11-02 04:49:20 | 68719476736 |
| 2019-11-02 05:11:40 | 2019-11-02 05:22:00 | 77309411328 |

Answer (score 3):

If you have a large DataFrame and you don't want OOM error problems, I suggest using [zipWithIndex()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.zipWithIndex.html):

```
df1 = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().toDF()
df2 = df1.select(col("_1.*"),col("_2").alias('increasing_id'))
df2.show()
```

where *df* is your initial DataFrame.

More solutions are shown by [Databricks documentation](https://kb.databricks.com/sql/gen-unique-increasing-values.html). Be careful with the [row_number()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.row_number.html) function that moves all the rows in one partition and can cause OutOfMemoryError errors.

Answer (score 0):

To merge dataframes of same size, use `zip` on rdds

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType

spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(1, "a"),(2, "b"),(3, "c")]).toDF(["id", "name"])
df2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(7, "x"),(8, "y"),(9, "z")]).toDF(["age", "address"])

schema = StructType(df1.schema.fields + df2.schema.fields)
df1df2 = df1.rdd.zip(df2.rdd).map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1])
spark.createDataFrame(df1df2, schema).show()
```

But note the following from help of the method,

```
    Assumes that the two RDDs have the same number of partitions and the same
    number of elements in each partition (e.g. one was made through
    a map on the other).
```