# Back and forward fill null values in a Spark Dataframe using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, null

I have a Spark dataframe where I have to create a window partition column ("desired_output"). This column has to back fill not-null values if there is no not-null first in the sort order value, and forward fill the other non-null values.

Here is a sample Spark dataframe with the desired output:

```
columns = ['user_id', 'date', 'desired_outcome']
data = [\
        ('1', None,         '2022-01-05'),\
        ('1', None,         '2022-01-05'),\
        ('1', '2022-01-05', '2022-01-05'),\
        ('1', None,         '2022-01-05'),\
        ('1', None,         '2022-01-05'),\
        ('2', None,         '2022-01-07'),\
        ('2', None,         '2022-01-07'),\
        ('2','2022-01-07',  '2022-01-07'),\
        ('2',None,          '2022-01-07'),\
        ('2','2022-01-09',  '2022-01-09'),\
        ('2',None,          '2022-01-09'),\
        ('3','2022-01-01',  '2022-01-01'),\
        ('3',None,          '2022-01-01'),\
        ('3',None,          '2022-01-01'),\
        ('3','2022-01-04',  '2022-01-04'),\
        ('3',None,          '2022-01-04'),\
        ('3',None,          '2022-01-04')]

sample_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
```

**[UPDATE]**

Based on the proposal solution of [@user238607](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3238085/user238607) (see the first of the answers below) I should have add this update outlining that the desired output doesn't depend on the date column values' chronological (or any other) order - the desired output depends only on the original sequence of the records within groups with the same `user_id` (this value column can be in general case of any type: numeric, string etc.). I have used the proposed code with some editions with another input and the calculated desired output isn't quite correct - the incorrect calculated values are marked with three dashes in the `correct` column:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


sc = spark #SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


data1 = [
        ('1', None,         '2022-02-12'),
        ('1', None,         '2022-02-12'),
        ('1', '2022-02-12', '2022-02-12'),
        ('1', None,         '2022-02-12'),
        ('1', None,         '2022-02-12'),
        ('2', None,         '2022-04-09'),
        ('2', None,         '2022-04-09'),
        ('2','2022-04-09',  '2022-04-09'),
        ('2',None,          '2022-04-09'),
        ('2','2022-01-07',  '2022-01-07'),
        ('2',None,          '2022-01-07'),
        ('3','2022-11-05',  '2022-11-05'),
        ('3',None,          '2022-11-05'),
        ('3',None,          '2022-11-05'),
        ('3','2022-01-04',  '2022-01-04'),
        ('3',None,          '2022-01-04'),
        ('3',None,          '2022-01-04'),
        ('3','2022-04-15',  '2022-04-15'),
        ('3',None,          '2022-04-15'),
        
        ]

columns = ['row_id', 'user_id', 'date', 'desired_outcome_given']

## following is done so that we have order of the rows.
data2 = [ (index, item[0], item[1], item[2]) for index, item in enumerate(data1) ]

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data2, schema=columns)

print("Given dataframe")
df1.show(n=10, truncate=False)

window_min_spec = Window.partitionBy("user_id").orderBy(F.col("row_id").asc()).rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)
window_max_spec = Window.partitionBy("user_id").orderBy(F.col("row_id").asc()).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

df1 = df1.withColumn("first_date", F.first("date", ignorenulls=True).over(window_min_spec))
df1 = df1.withColumn("last_date", F.last("date", ignorenulls=True).over(window_max_spec))
print("Calculated first and last dates")
df1.show(truncate=False)
print("Final dataframe")
#output = df1.select('row_id', 'user_id', 'date').withColumn("desired_outcome_calculated", F.least(*["min_date", "max_date"])).select("desired_outcome_given", "desired_outcome_calculated")
output = df1.\
            withColumn("desired_outcome_calculated", F.least(*["first_date", "last_date"]))\
            .withColumn("correct", F.when(F.col("desired_outcome_given") == F.col("desired_outcome_calculated"),F.lit('true')).otherwise('---'))\
            .select('row_id', 'user_id', 'date', "desired_outcome_given", "desired_outcome_calculated", "correct")
output.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
Given dataframe
+------+-------+----------+---------------------+
|row_id|user_id|date      |desired_outcome_given|
+------+-------+----------+---------------------+
|0     |1      |NULL      |2022-02-12           |
|1     |1      |NULL      |2022-02-12           |
|2     |1      |2022-02-12|2022-02-12           |
|3     |1      |NULL      |2022-02-12           |
|4     |1      |NULL      |2022-02-12           |
|5     |2      |NULL      |2022-04-09           |
|6     |2      |NULL      |2022-04-09           |
|7     |2      |2022-04-09|2022-04-09           |
|8     |2      |NULL      |2022-04-09           |
|9     |2      |2022-01-07|2022-01-07           |
+------+-------+----------+---------------------+
only showing top 10 rows

Calculated first and last dates
+------+-------+----------+---------------------+----------+----------+
|row_id|user_id|date      |desired_outcome_given|first_date|last_date |
+------+-------+----------+---------------------+----------+----------+
|0     |1      |NULL      |2022-02-12           |2022-02-12|NULL      |
|1     |1      |NULL      |2022-02-12           |2022-02-12|NULL      |
|2     |1      |2022-02-12|2022-02-12           |2022-02-12|2022-02-12|
|3     |1      |NULL      |2022-02-12           |NULL      |2022-02-12|
|4     |1      |NULL      |2022-02-12           |NULL      |2022-02-12|
|5     |2      |NULL      |2022-04-09           |2022-04-09|NULL      |
|6     |2      |NULL      |2022-04-09           |2022-04-09|NULL      |
|7     |2      |2022-04-09|2022-04-09           |2022-04-09|2022-04-09|
|8     |2      |NULL      |2022-04-09           |2022-01-07|2022-04-09|
|9     |2      |2022-01-07|2022-01-07           |2022-01-07|2022-01-07|
|10    |2      |NULL      |2022-01-07           |NULL      |2022-01-07|
|11    |3      |2022-11-05|2022-11-05           |2022-11-05|2022-11-05|
|12    |3      |NULL      |2022-11-05           |2022-01-04|2022-11-05|
|13    |3      |NULL      |2022-11-05           |2022-01-04|2022-11-05|
|14    |3      |2022-01-04|2022-01-04           |2022-01-04|2022-01-04|
|15    |3      |NULL      |2022-01-04           |2022-04-15|2022-01-04|
|16    |3      |NULL      |2022-01-04           |2022-04-15|2022-01-04|
|17    |3      |2022-04-15|2022-04-15           |2022-04-15|2022-04-15|
|18    |3      |NULL      |2022-04-15           |NULL      |2022-04-15|
+------+-------+----------+---------------------+----------+----------+

Final dataframe
+------+-------+----------+---------------------+--------------------------+-------+
|row_id|user_id|date      |desired_outcome_given|desired_outcome_calculated|correct|
+------+-------+----------+---------------------+--------------------------+-------+
|0     |1      |NULL      |2022-02-12           |2022-02-12                |true   |
|1     |1      |NULL      |2022-02-12           |2022-02-12                |true   |
|2     |1      |2022-02-12|2022-02-12           |2022-02-12                |true   |
|3     |1      |NULL      |2022-02-12           |2022-02-12                |true   |
|4     |1      |NULL      |2022-02-12           |2022-02-12                |true   |
|5     |2      |NULL      |2022-04-09           |2022-04-09                |true   |
|6     |2      |NULL      |2022-04-09           |2022-04-09                |true   |
|7     |2      |2022-04-09|2022-04-09           |2022-04-09                |true   |
|8     |2      |NULL      |2022-04-09           |2022-01-07                |---    |
|9     |2      |2022-01-07|2022-01-07           |2022-01-07                |true   |
|10    |2      |NULL      |2022-01-07           |2022-01-07                |true   |
|11    |3      |2022-11-05|2022-11-05           |2022-11-05                |true   |
|12    |3      |NULL      |2022-11-05           |2022-01-04                |---    |
|13    |3      |NULL      |2022-11-05           |2022-01-04                |---    |
|14    |3      |2022-01-04|2022-01-04           |2022-01-04                |true   |
|15    |3      |NULL      |2022-01-04           |2022-01-04                |true   |
|16    |3      |NULL      |2022-01-04           |2022-01-04                |true   |
|17    |3      |2022-04-15|2022-04-15           |2022-04-15                |true   |
|18    |3      |NULL      |2022-04-15           |2022-04-15                |true   |
+------+-------+----------+---------------------+--------------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


data1 = [
        ('1', None,         '2022-01-05'),
        ('1', None,         '2022-01-05'),
        ('1', '2022-01-05', '2022-01-05'),
        ('1', None,         '2022-01-05'),
        ('1', None,         '2022-01-05'),
        ('2', None,         '2022-01-07'),
        ('2', None,         '2022-01-07'),
        ('2','2022-01-07',  '2022-01-07'),
        ('2',None,          '2022-01-07'),
        ('2','2022-01-09',  '2022-01-09'),
        ('2',None,          '2022-01-09'),
        ('3','2022-01-01',  '2022-01-01'),
        ('3',None,          '2022-01-01'),
        ('3',None,          '2022-01-01'),
        ('3','2022-01-04',  '2022-01-04'),
        ('3',None,          '2022-01-04'),
        ('3',None,          '2022-01-04')]

columns = ['row_id', 'user_id', 'date', 'desired_outcome_given']

## following is done so that we have order of the rows.
data2 = [ (index, item[0], item[1], item[2]) for index, item in enumerate(data1) ]

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data2, schema=columns)

print("Given dataframe")
df1.show(n=10, truncate=False)

window_min_spec = Window.partitionBy("user_id").orderBy(F.col("row_id").asc()).rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)
window_max_spec = Window.partitionBy("user_id").orderBy(F.col("row_id").asc()).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

df1 = df1.withColumn("min_date", F.first("date", ignorenulls=True).over(window_min_spec))
df1 = df1.withColumn("max_date", F.last("date", ignorenulls=True).over(window_max_spec))
print("Calculated min and max")
df1.show(truncate=False)
print("Final dataframe")
output = df1.withColumn("desired_outcome_calculated", F.least(*["min_date", "max_date"])).select("desired_outcome_given", "desired_outcome_calculated")
output.show(truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
Given dataframe
+------+-------+----------+---------------------+
|row_id|user_id|date      |desired_outcome_given|
+------+-------+----------+---------------------+
|0     |1      |null      |2022-01-05           |
|1     |1      |null      |2022-01-05           |
|2     |1      |2022-01-05|2022-01-05           |
|3     |1      |null      |2022-01-05           |
|4     |1      |null      |2022-01-05           |
|5     |2      |null      |2022-01-07           |
|6     |2      |null      |2022-01-07           |
|7     |2      |2022-01-07|2022-01-07           |
|8     |2      |null      |2022-01-07           |
|9     |2      |2022-01-09|2022-01-09           |
+------+-------+----------+---------------------+
only showing top 10 rows

Calculated min and max
+------+-------+----------+---------------------+----------+----------+
|row_id|user_id|date      |desired_outcome_given|min_date  |max_date  |
+------+-------+----------+---------------------+----------+----------+
|0     |1      |null      |2022-01-05           |2022-01-05|null      |
|1     |1      |null      |2022-01-05           |2022-01-05|null      |
|2     |1      |2022-01-05|2022-01-05           |2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
|3     |1      |null      |2022-01-05           |null      |2022-01-05|
|4     |1      |null      |2022-01-05           |null      |2022-01-05|
|5     |2      |null      |2022-01-07           |2022-01-07|null      |
|6     |2      |null      |2022-01-07           |2022-01-07|null      |
|7     |2      |2022-01-07|2022-01-07           |2022-01-07|2022-01-07|
|8     |2      |null      |2022-01-07           |2022-01-09|2022-01-07|
|9     |2      |2022-01-09|2022-01-09           |2022-01-09|2022-01-09|
|10    |2      |null      |2022-01-09           |null      |2022-01-09|
|11    |3      |2022-01-01|2022-01-01           |2022-01-01|2022-01-01|
|12    |3      |null      |2022-01-01           |2022-01-04|2022-01-01|
|13    |3      |null      |2022-01-01           |2022-01-04|2022-01-01|
|14    |3      |2022-01-04|2022-01-04           |2022-01-04|2022-01-04|
|15    |3      |null      |2022-01-04           |null      |2022-01-04|
|16    |3      |null      |2022-01-04           |null      |2022-01-04|
+------+-------+----------+---------------------+----------+----------+

Final dataframe
+---------------------+--------------------------+
|desired_outcome_given|desired_outcome_calculated|
+---------------------+--------------------------+
|2022-01-05           |2022-01-05                |
|2022-01-05           |2022-01-05                |
|2022-01-05           |2022-01-05                |
|2022-01-05           |2022-01-05                |
|2022-01-05           |2022-01-05                |
|2022-01-07           |2022-01-07                |
|2022-01-07           |2022-01-07                |
|2022-01-07           |2022-01-07                |
|2022-01-07           |2022-01-07                |
|2022-01-09           |2022-01-09                |
|2022-01-09           |2022-01-09                |
|2022-01-01           |2022-01-01                |
|2022-01-01           |2022-01-01                |
|2022-01-01           |2022-01-01                |
|2022-01-04           |2022-01-04                |
|2022-01-04           |2022-01-04                |
|2022-01-04           |2022-01-04                |
+---------------------+--------------------------+
```

EDIT : As per new update, here's how I would do it.

```
columns = ['row_id', 'user_id', 'date', 'desired_outcome_given']

## following is done so that we have order of the rows.
data2 = [ (index, item[0], item[1], item[2]) for index, item in enumerate(data1) ]

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data2, schema=columns)

print("Given dataframe")
df1.show(n=10, truncate=False)

window_fillup_notnull_spec = Window.partitionBy("user_id").orderBy(F.col("row_id").asc()).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0 )
window_fillbelow_notnull_spec = Window.partitionBy("user_id").orderBy(F.col("row_id").asc()).rowsBetween( 0, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df1 = df1.withColumn("up_values", F.last("date", ignorenulls=True).over(window_fillup_notnull_spec))
df1 = df1.withColumn("below_values", F.first("date", ignorenulls=True).over(window_fillbelow_notnull_spec))
print("Calculated min and max")
df1.show(truncate=False)
print("Final dataframe")
output = df1.withColumn("desired_outcome_calculated", F.when(  F.col("up_values").isNotNull(), F.col("up_values"))
                                                             .otherwise(F.col("below_values")) ).select("desired_outcome_given", "desired_outcome_calculated")
output.show(truncate=False)
```

Output is as follows :

```
Final dataframe
+---------------------+--------------------------+
|desired_outcome_given|desired_outcome_calculated|
+---------------------+--------------------------+
|2022-02-12           |2022-02-12                |
|2022-02-12           |2022-02-12                |
|2022-02-12           |2022-02-12                |
|2022-02-12           |2022-02-12                |
|2022-02-12           |2022-02-12                |
|2022-04-09           |2022-04-09                |
|2022-04-09           |2022-04-09                |
|2022-04-09           |2022-04-09                |
|2022-04-09           |2022-04-09                |
|2022-01-07           |2022-01-07                |
|2022-01-07           |2022-01-07                |
|2022-11-05           |2022-11-05                |
|2022-11-05           |2022-11-05                |
|2022-11-05           |2022-11-05                |
|2022-01-04           |2022-01-04                |
|2022-01-04           |2022-01-04                |
|2022-01-04           |2022-01-04                |
|2022-04-15           |2022-04-15                |
|2022-04-15           |2022-04-15                |
+---------------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposal solution. I have added the update section to my original question to note that this solution results in some incorrect calculations. Do you see how to make editions to your code to make it working in all the cases?

Comment: @ShamilS : I update my answer. It is somewhat cleaner. But I am doing essentially what you did in your updated answer.

Comment: Yes, the corrected code line in your edited code version `output = df1.withColumn("desired_outcome_calculated", F.when(  F.col("up_values").isNotNull(), F.col("up_values")).otherwise(F.col("below_values")) ).select("desired_outcome_given", "desired_outcome_calculated")`  makes all the difference. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on a very helpful proposal answer of [@user238607](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3238085/user238607) (see above) I have done some homework and here is a generic utility forward/backward filling method I've been looking for:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
```

```
sc = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .master("local[*]")\
    .appName('fb_fill_method_sample')\
    .getOrCreate()
```

```
def fb_fill(df, 
            grouping_column_name, 
            value_column_name, 
            row_num_column_name = "row_num",
            temp_column_name = "temp_column",
            preserve_generated_row_num = False):
    dfx = df
    row_num_column_exists = row_num_column_name in df.columns
    if (not(row_num_column_exists)):
      # add a unique consecutive row number to dataframe in pyspark
      # credits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53082891/adding-a-unique-consecutive-row-number-to-dataframe-in-pyspark
      dfx = dfx.withColumn(temp_column_name, F.lit("XYZ"))
      w = Window().partitionBy(temp_column_name).orderBy(F.lit('X'))
      dfx = dfx.withColumn(row_num_column_name, F.row_number().over(w)).drop(temp_column_name)

      # rearrange columns setting {row_num_column_name} as the first column (if it's a generated column)
      rearanged_cols = [row_num_column_name] + ([c for c in dfx.columns if c not in [row_num_column_name]])
      dfx = dfx.select(*rearanged_cols)

    window_first_spec = Window.partitionBy(grouping_column_name).orderBy(F.col(row_num_column_name).asc()).rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)
    window_last_spec = Window.partitionBy(grouping_column_name).orderBy(F.col(row_num_column_name).asc()).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

    dfx = dfx.withColumn(temp_column_name, F.last(value_column_name, ignorenulls=True).over(window_last_spec))
    dfx = dfx.withColumn(value_column_name, F.when(F.col(temp_column_name).isNull(), F.first(value_column_name, ignorenulls=True).over(window_first_spec)).otherwise(F.col(temp_column_name)))
    
    dfx = dfx.drop(temp_column_name)
    if (not(row_num_column_exists) and not(preserve_generated_row_num)): dfx = dfx.drop(row_num_column_name)
    
    return dfx
```

```
data = [
        ('1', None,         '2022-02-12'),
        ('1', None,         '2022-02-12'),
        ('1', '2022-02-12', '2022-02-12'),
        ('1', None,         '2022-02-12'),
        ('1', None,         '2022-02-12'),
        ('2', None,         '2022-04-09'),
        ('2', None,         '2022-04-09'),
        ('2','2022-04-09',  '2022-04-09'),
        ('2',None,          '2022-04-09'),
        ('2','2022-01-07',  '2022-01-07'),
        ('2',None,          '2022-01-07'),
        ('3','2022-11-05',  '2022-11-05'),
        ('3',None,          '2022-11-05'),
        ('3',None,          '2022-11-05'),
        ('3','2022-01-04',  '2022-01-04'),
        ('3',None,          '2022-01-04'),
        ('3',None,          '2022-01-04'),
        ('3','2022-04-15',  '2022-04-15'),
        ('3',None,          '2022-04-15'),
        
        ]

columns = ['user_id', 'date', 'desired_value_given']

sample_df = sc.createDataFrame(data, columns)
```

```
result_df = fb_fill(sample_df, "user_id", "date")
result_df = result_df.withColumn("correct", F.when(F.col("date") == F.col("desired_value_given"), F.lit('true')).otherwise(F.lit('---')))
result_df.show()
```

```
+-------+----------+-------------------+-------+
|user_id|      date|desired_value_given|correct|
+-------+----------+-------------------+-------+
|      1|2022-02-12|         2022-02-12|   true|
|      1|2022-02-12|         2022-02-12|   true|
|      1|2022-02-12|         2022-02-12|   true|
|      1|2022-02-12|         2022-02-12|   true|
|      1|2022-02-12|         2022-02-12|   true|
|      2|2022-04-09|         2022-04-09|   true|
|      2|2022-04-09|         2022-04-09|   true|
|      2|2022-04-09|         2022-04-09|   true|
|      2|2022-04-09|         2022-04-09|   true|
|      2|2022-01-07|         2022-01-07|   true|
|      2|2022-01-07|         2022-01-07|   true|
|      3|2022-11-05|         2022-11-05|   true|
|      3|2022-11-05|         2022-11-05|   true|
|      3|2022-11-05|         2022-11-05|   true|
|      3|2022-01-04|         2022-01-04|   true|
|      3|2022-01-04|         2022-01-04|   true|
|      3|2022-01-04|         2022-01-04|   true|
|      3|2022-04-15|         2022-04-15|   true|
|      3|2022-04-15|         2022-04-15|   true|
+-------+----------+-------------------+-------+
```

Please provide your comments/corrections if you'll find any bugs and if you know more concise and effective solutions as the developed method is supposed to be applied for rather large source datasets with a few hundreds of thousands of data rows.