# F.monotonically_increasing_id() returns long random

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

```
x = df.withColumn("id_col", F.monotonically_increasing_id())
```

returns random long integers instead of sorted int numbers[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBo93.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using monotonically\_increasing\_id() for assigning row number to pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209667/using-monotonically-increasing-id-for-assigning-row-number-to-pyspark-datafram)

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is the expected behavior of the function. From the documentation

> The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and
>   unique, but not consecutive.
>       The current implementation puts the partition ID in the upper 31 bits, and the record number
>       within each partition in the lower 33 bits. The assumption is that the data frame has
>       less than 1 billion partitions, and each partition has less than 8 billion records

This is why you see long random integers. They may not be sequential but they are in increasing order and for all practical purposes, unique.