# Can we give a Sequence Id for rows in Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to spark and I have around 10000 rows in a datafile to read

```
SparkSession sessionSpark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .config(sparkConf)
            .getOrCreate();


Dataset<Row> dataset = sessionSpark.read.parquet("s3://databucket/files/")
```

I have a usecase to add a row number to every row in the dataset , the row number should start from 1 to 10000 (since the file has 10000 records ) , is it possible to assign a row number and we know spark shuffles the data but let's say even after rerunning the same file twice from the application , the row number generated should be the same , is it possible to do ?

Comment: If you use ```monotonically_increasing_id ``` function & it has some drawbacks & how to fix that .. check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209667/using-monotonically-increasing-id-for-assigning-row-number-to-pyspark-datafram

Comment: i will post a fuller answer but in scala

Answer (score 2):

`monotonically_increasing_id()` would add incremental id for your rows

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
Dataset<Row> dataset = sessionSpark.read.parquet("s3://databucket/files/").withColumn("rowNum", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

From official Spark Docs

> A column expression that generates monotonically increasing 64-bit
>   integers.
>
> The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and
>   unique, but not consecutive. The current implementation puts the
>   partition ID in the upper 31 bits, and the record number within each
>   partition in the lower 33 bits. The assumption is that the data frame
>   has less than 1 billion partitions, and each partition has less than 8
>   billion records.
>
> As an example, consider a `DataFrame` with two partitions, each with 3
>   records. This expression would return the following IDs:
>
> {{{ 0, 1, 2, 8589934592 (1L << 33), 8589934593, 8589934594. }}}

Comment: Are you 100% sure this will keep the IDs always the same? Like ID 1 will always be record X?

Comment: So what you quote, it means that if I change the number of partitions I get different IDs? I am myself interested in this because it is a use case I have, and I used hashes to be 100% sure it is the same.

Comment: no the quote means that the id will be a unique no. for each row in any Dataframe/Dataset. It just the unique set of ids are allocated across partitions in-order to make compute faster.

Comment: Cool. I will use it personally and you deserve a +1, but I think this does not do what was asked. It is not 1 to 1000, consecutive. It is "random".

Comment: Annoyed with the -1 vote I got which is indeed zipWithIndex that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: A solution that complies to the ID being consecutive and starting at 1

If you can order them by something, it should be possible. This example might be scala, but the main part is still the SQL part.

```scala
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("alfa", 10), ("beta", 20), ("gama", 5))).toDF("word", "count")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("wordcount")

// MAIN PART
val tmpTable = spark.sqlContext.sql("select row_number() over (order by count) as index,word,count from wordcount")

tmpTable.show()

+-----+----+-----+
|index|word|count|
+-----+----+-----+
|    1|gama|    5|
|    2|alfa|   10|
|    3|beta|   20|
+-----+----+-----+
```

**EDIT**: If you don't need plain numbers, go with a hash of row. It is better.

Comment: Without a partition by clause won't this pull all of the data to a single partition which may cause performance problems? I solved that particular problem whn using dense_rank by addition a dummy partitionBy(lit(0)) clause to my WindowSpec

Answer (score 0):

Not in Java as I do not specialize in that, but in Scala. Should be easy enough to convert for you. Just an example I have using DS with case classes:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}
import spark.implicits._

// Gen some example data via DF, can come from files, ordering in those files assumed. I.e. no need to sort.
val df = Seq(
  ("1 February"), ("n"), ("c"), ("b"), 
  ("2 February"), ("hh"), ("www"), ("e"), 
  ("3 February"), ("y"), ("s"), ("j"),
  ("1 March"), ("c"), ("b"), ("x"),
  ("1 March"), ("c"), ("b"), ("x"),
  ("2 March"), ("c"), ("b"), ("x"),
  ("3 March"), ("c"), ("b"), ("x"), ("y"), ("z")
           ).toDF("line")

// Define Case Classes to avoid Row aspects on df --> rdd --> to DF. 
case class X(line: String)   
case class Xtra(key: Long, line: String)

// Add the Seq Num using zipWithIndex. Then convert back, but will have a struct to deal wit.
// You can avoid the struct if using Row and such. But general idea should be clear.
val rdd = df.as[X].rdd.zipWithIndex().map{case (v,k) => (k,v)}
val ds = rdd.toDF("key", "line").as[Xtra]
ds.show(100,false)
```

returns:

```
+---+------------+
|key|line        |
+---+------------+
|0  |[1 February]|
|1  |[n]         |  
|2  |[c]         |
...
```

The answers to-date do not meet the needs as question provide but if only 10K rows then the single partition is not an issue. Although for 10K rows one has to ask a few questions.

If you don't mind Row, here is another approach:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField,StructType,IntegerType, ArrayType, LongType}

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1.0, 2.0), (0.0, -1.0), (3.0, 4.0), (6.0, -2.3))).toDF("x", "y")
val newSchema = StructType(df.schema.fields ++ Array(StructField("rowid", LongType, false)))

val rddWithId = df.rdd.zipWithIndex
val dfZippedWithId =  spark.createDataFrame(rddWithId.map{ case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Array(index))}, newSchema)
```

Comment: @thebluephanton does `zipWithIndex` guarantee the same order if we run the same file multiple times..for ex: does the ID in the first run is always the same Id in the second run too ?

Comment: assuming same content, and not regenerated, yes.

Comment: moreover no shuffling has yet occured

Comment: zipwithinded is 1 reason for rdds still.zwi is narrow transformation. reading a file has block, partition pointers that understand sequence