# Pyspark: Join two dataframes which doesn't have a common column (The order of the rows should remain same)

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, left-join, outer-join

I have a spark dataframe(df) consisting of features on which my model is trained on and 3 extra features ID, label and status(these 3 are not used in my model training). I'm using a model registered on mlflow to predict on these columns but before I send to prediction I'm removing 3 columns i.e. ID, label and status and storing it in a intermediate dataframe.

Now after passing df through the registered mlflow model I get a new column(Probability) in **result_df** having my probabilities(This is a binary classification model).

Now I want add back these probabilities to the original df without changing the order i.e. the ID, label and status should get assigned to the corresponding predicted probability.

My final table should have ID,label, status and it's probability.
NOTE: df and result_df doesn't have any common column to perform the join. SO I've used monotically_increasing_id() to perform the join

I've tried below codes:

```
df=df.withColumn('index',montonically_increasing_id())
result_df=result_df.withColumn('index',montonically_increasing_id())

final_df=df.join(result_df,'index','left')
```

When I do left join, in the resultant dataframe final_df there are nulls in ID column.

And `df.select('ID','label','status').exceptAll(final_df.select('ID','label','status'))`  there are lot of different rows.

But when I do left outer join:

`final_df=df.join(result_df,'index','left_outer')`
`df.select('ID','label','status').exceptAll(final_df.select('ID','label','status'))`  seems fine but there are null values in **Probability** column.

Please let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: Monotonically increaing ID won't work as both will have different IDs, know why - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209667/using-monotonically-increasing-id-for-assigning-row-number-to-pyspark-datafram